# Budgeting feature for django ecommerce web app

Tags: django

Can anyone help me with login to build a budget feature within a ecommerce platform. i have this project I am designing for my final year project but i want to design a page where user can find multiple product within a specific price. Let say the user want to a shirt, bag and shoe but have 7000, I want the app to return all the three product that can be bought with 7000.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    ....
    price = models.FloatField()
```

you can filter with the price field and get an exact match,
for more complex queries consider using [lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/lookups/) along with [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) object

```bash
Product.objects.filter(price=7000)
```

note: `7000` can be passed as a query parameter to the corresponding `view` function mapped in `URLcofig`